# how to test ruby scripts, in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I got some cron jobs that i wanna test, where should i out them, how can i run them with rails commands and if the got some dependencies like files and stuff how can i load their fixture?

to be more concrete lets say i got a rb file thats reads a file from a the app folder, do some parsing, and writes stuff to db.

where to put the test and how to connect it with rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My method is to create a folder called app/jobs, then name the classes in the folder accordingly. The jobs are then called using script/rails runner. The runner interface loads rails and you have access to all of your models.

```
class SomeOddJob
  def run
    #do something
  end
end
```

from your cron job you'd run the job like this (in production mode):

> 0 5  *  *  * /path/to/script/rails runner -e production "SomeOddJob.run"

Comment: I guess I left out the testing part which is the whole point of your question. With a setup like the one above, since your cron jobs are basically just Rails models, you can write unit tests or specs, load fixtures, etc, just like you do with a plain old rails model.

Comment: I didn't mention, but I'm new to ruby and ruby on rails, so if you can, please add some more information